# Click event outside series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Currently I use `plotOptions.series.events.click` to listen for clicks in my chart. However this requires the user to click exactly on the point. How can I extend the click area vertically so that the user can click above or below the point to get that point object?

I tried to use `chart.events.click` but I don't think I can retrieve the point objects that are near the click point. Hovering anywhere on the chart shows the tooltip with the correct values of the points. I'd like to mimic this functionality but for clicks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an internal Highcharts function for searching a point in a specific series.

```
Series.prototype.searchPoint(event : Event, compareX : boolean)
```

It will allow you to find the point on chart.events.click.

```
 chart: {
    events: {
      click: function(e) {
        var point = this.series[0].searchPoint(e, true);
        point && point.update({
            color: 'red'
        });
        console.log(point);
    }
  }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/qgq0na6z/1/